# Wordpress: Is there plugin to check if signing-in user is in a google sheet?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, google-sheets

I manage web pages for our club. There is a google spreadsheet storing all members.

Is it possible to check if the signing-in/up user is in google spreadsheet? Is there any plugin with this functionality? Something like LDAP with google sheet.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for [WPGSI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgsi/) but it integrates Wordpress and Google spreadsheet.

But there are other ways to do this depending on what form do you use, if you use wordpress form plugins such as contact form 7, wp forms or ninja forms, they have addons to record all the signing and inquiries and there you can just import your sheets in the following format xls or csv.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe different point of view would help. But, We manage list of club members in a sheet. We add or delete them. And after that we would like to allow new users to register and sign in to the site and keep outside deleted members. Members are in the sheet and I don't want to create duplicity of the primary member list.